Error trying to run a glmer model: drop.unused.levels = TRUE, : variable lengths differ
I am trying to run a glmer model (family=binomial). This is a simplified version of my data created with dput()
structure(list(subject = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5), Acc = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), total_TikTok = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 7.28666666666667, 
7.28666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 6.85666666666667, 
6.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 7.85666666666667, 
7.85666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), IntegerTotalTikTok = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 500L), class = "data.frame")

I have a column called subject I am using in the random structure of the model. The outcome variable is Acc and the predictor is IntegerTotalTikTok. The model looks like this:
glmer(Acc ~ IntegerTikTokScale + (1|subject),data = Data2,family = "binomial")
This gives me the error:
drop.unused.levels = TRUE,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'IntegerTikTokScale')

What I don't understand is that the IntegerTikTokScale is (or should be) the same as the total_TikTok scale, with the only difference that the latter has decimals and the former has been rounded to integers with the following code:
IntegerTikTokScale <- round(Data_Inhibition$total_TikTok,0)

This should have just rounded all values to whole values (e.g. a 6.7 becomes a 7). Yet, when I run the model above using the total_TikTok column, the model runs. And when I try running it with IntegerTikTokScale, I get the error mentioned in the title. I check that there are no NA's and the length of the colums is of course the same (otherwise I wouldn't have been able to add the column to the data.frame in the first place.
Any idea on what might be causing this, or how to fix it?

There is no IntegerTikTokScale in your data, only IntegerTotalTikTok. If you have a variable called IntegerTikTokScale in your global environment, but it doesn't have the same number of observations then I think you would get this error. The model appears to run with IntegerTotalTikTok.

@Axeman, please post as an answer? I couldn't reproduce this in the way I thought was most likely (by adding NA values in some of the model variables that would get trimmed when the model frame was constructed, leaving a mismatch with a global variable commensurate with the original data frame), but I could get the error by defining newi <- sample(1:10, size = 40, replace = TRUE) and including it in the model ...

Your code:
IntegerTikTokScale <- round(Data_Inhibition$total_TikTok,0)

shows that you created IntegerTikTokScale as a global variable, and from a different data.frame then what you are using in your model. If Data2 and Data_Inhibition have a different number of rows, then you will get this issue, which is my best guess at what happened.
We all get mixed up with our data.frames and variables sometimes. Try to use defensive coding to guard against these kinds of issues. In particular, try not to create loose vectors that do not live a data.frame when you are modelling. The data argument makes it clear what the context of the variables is, and ensures that e.g. missing values are dealt with correctly. Basically, if you had written:
Data2$IntegerTikTokScale <- round(Data_Inhibition$total_TikTok,0)

you would have gotten a warning about the wrong length right there. Or if you would have written:
Data_Inhibition$IntegerTikTokScale <- round(Data_Inhibition$total_TikTok,0)

then your glmer call would have given you a more informative error: the variable does not exist in Data2.

You are completely right. Although I did add this vector to the Data data.frame, so I would have expected to get some variable length warnings there. Still, thanks for the advice, I'll make sure I create vectors inside data.frames from now on.

Well, 1 minute after posting this I realized the round() function hadn't really converted the vector like I intended to. I used as.integer instead, and the numbers where now correctly turned from numeric to integers, and the error is no longer there.
I am still curious as to why the error happened, since even though the conversion wasn't  accurate, R still shows the vector I created with round() is a numerical vector of the same length as Acc and subject. I don't understand why it gives the "variables length differ" error.

I doubt this explanation; it is more likely that you did something slightly different with where you got the variable from, or whether you incorporated it back into Data2 rather than leaving it as a global variable.  If you can give us a reproducible example that backs up this answer I will be surprised and interested ...
